# How to put R Markdown chunks in different HTML-tabs?

Tags: html, r, tabs, r-markdown

I have an R markdown page with a lot of chunks. Is it possible to render an HTML-page in which the chunks appear in different tabs?

As an example I use this .Rmd file:

````
---
title: "Example"
output: html_document
---

# Tab 1

```{r}
summary(cars)
```

# Tab 2

```{r, echo=FALSE}
plot(cars)
```
````

Now I want to render an HTML-page with the content of the two chunks in two different tabs. How can I do that?

This is how it basically has to look like.

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This works with the latest release of rmarkdown.
You may have to use the following to install:

```
install.packages("rmarkdown", type = "source")
```

Onse this is done, try this:

````
---
title: "Example"
output: html_document
---


## Tabbed Example {.tabset}

### Tab1

```{r}
summary(cars)
```

### Tab2

```{r, echo=FALSE}
plot(cars)
```
````

Comment: this is too awesome, should be highlighted - thank you sir!