# Rmarkdown display images as tabs

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am displaying some images as below.

````
```{r}
hf <- list.files("path/",".png",full.names=T)
knitr::include_graphics(hf)
```
````

This displays the images one below the other. Is there a way to display them as tabs? I imagine some option like this.

````
```{r,class.output="tabset"}
```
````

Comment: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/html-tabs.html, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34877350/how-to-put-r-markdown-chunks-in-different-html-tabs like this?

Comment: Yea, it's very much related, but those are sections and not individual images from a chunk. I can think of some hacky way to do it, but was just wondering if there is something straight-forward.

Comment: Nothing comes to mind, really. The hacky ways (which I'm sure you thought of already) are either doing a loop in an `asis` chunk using `tabset`, or using shiny to create a `tabsetPanel`